# Issue with login Prompt of SharePoint Sites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, kerberos, network

There is a sudden issue in our SharePoint Servers and we are faced with continuous login prompt coming up while trying to open SharePoint Sites. It is happening in all server and SharePoint team is working with Load Balancing team and Network team.

As a SharePoint Admin, When I am trying to log in to the SharePoint site, I am getting this error logged in Event Viewer under System section:

EventID-7

```
The digitally signed Privilege Attribute Certificate (PAC) that contains the authorization information for client MyID in realm domain.net could not be validated.
 This error is usually caused by domain trust failures; please contact your system administrator.
```

I checked this google found [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd348751(v=ws.10).aspx).

I implemented the steps mentioned, still issue persists.

Does it have anything to do with login prompt?

Any help,any knowledge any one??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below link, it might be helpful to you

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/scottstewart/2014/09/15/disableloopbackcheck-when-routing-through-a-load-balancer-powershell-sample-included/

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is the security context. When we authenticate in Internet Explorer, we are providing our credentials within the context of a single application which is nothing but “Internet Explorer”. Then once we click on a document or open a document from SharePoint, we have just created another security context. On top of this, if we try to open Microsoft files like word, excel, this will again try to connect the office online server and authenticate there with another context. This continues as much as applications are involved in that particular SharePoint page or resource.

Microsoft says about this issue is – it is a known issue or by the design of SharePoint.

**How to fix this issue?**

Now, we knew that what root cause of this issue, so we need to fix this issue. In order to fix this issue we need to perform one of the following or with the combinations.

- Implement Kerberos authentication in your SharePoint server.
- Connect all SharePoint servers those are part of SharePoint farm
  under a    single common domain and make sure all users available in
  the single    active directory domain the same as SharePoint server
  domain.
- Make sure that there are no network devices, like proxy servers or
  firewalls  which unveil the authentication information from the
  network communications between your local laptop/desktop and the
  SharePoint servers.
- If you have enabled Anonymous authentication then we need to    make
  sure that Require Use Remote Interfaces permission is Disabled .
  Select your web application from Central admin -> Click on
  Authentication Providers -> Click on the Default zone. Then we will get the below page. Here if we see enable anonymous access is checked then ensure that Require Use Remote Interfaces permission is unchecked.
- Make sure that SharePoint Web Services IIS website authentication
  the configuration is correct means need to ensure the SharePoint Web
  Services IIS website is having same authentication as your web
  the application where you are facing problem. To verify this follow this
  navigation – Go to IIS server and select the “SharePoint Web
  Services” web application and compare the below authentication with
  your SharePoint authentication.
- If you have DNS Proxy enabled, it is recommended that disable the DNS
  proxy and test your web application.

For details, you may refer to the below article:

[Why multiple times SharePoint users are asked to enter the credentials?](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-2/sharepoint-troubleshooting/why-multiple-times-sharepoint-users-are-asked-to-enter-the-credentials/)